# What is the Best Ad Network for a Flex Website?

Tags: advertising

Can anyone recommend an ad network for a Flex website other than OpenX and Mochi Ads.

I desperately need to get some ads on my site. Any advice?

Comment: what is flex? describe more.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a great list of ad networks at http://adsreview.net
Its easy to find the CPC, CPM or CPA network that fits your needs and requirements.